# Responsive Bootstrap Carousel with two elements per slide

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, carousel

I've been trying to make my Carousel responsive with no results. I'm showing two items (div structures) per slide and I want to show just one item for mobile resolutions.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="recentReleases" class="carousel slide carouselRecentReleases" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="layout-row">
        <!-- Comunicat 1 --> 
          <div class="layout-6-cols">
            <div class="release">
              <div class="release__header">
                <span class="release__header-date">02 Octubre 2017</span>
                <span class="tag-badge badgeLightBlue">Corporatiu</span>
              </div>
              <div class="release__body">
                <img class="release__body-image" src="./images/img-release-1.png" alt="images release 1">
                <p class="release__body--text">1. Connexió a internet per a tothom a tota la flota de busos de TMB</p>
              </div>
              <div class="release__footer">
                <span class="release__footer-attachedFiles">2 adjunts</span>
                <a href="#" class="release__footer-link">Llegir més</a>
              </div>
            </div>  
          </div>
        <!-- Comunicat 2 -->
          <div class="layout-6-cols">
            <div class="release">
              <div class="release__header">
                <span class="release__header-date">02 Octubre 2017</span>
                <span class="tag-badge badgeRed">Canvis de Personals</span>
              </div>
              <div class="release__body">
                <img class="release__body-image" src="./images/img-release-1.png" alt="images release 1">
                <p class="release__body--text">2. Noves incorporacions en el departament de recursos humans</p>
              </div>
              <div class="release__footer">
                <a href="#" class="release__footer-link">Llegir més</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>                                                                 
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="layout-row">
        <!-- Comunicat 3 -->
          <div class="layout-6-cols">
            <div class="release">
              <div class="release__header">
                <span class="release__header-date">02 Octubre 2017</span>
                <span class="tag-badge badgeRed">Canvis de Personals</span>
              </div>
              <div class="release__body">
                <img class="release__body-image" src="./images/img-release-1.png" alt="images release 1">
                <p class="release__body--text">3. Noves incorporacions en el departament de recursos humans</p>
              </div>
              <div class="release__footer">
                <a href="#" class="release__footer-link">Llegir més</a>
              </div>
            </div>  
          </div>
        <!-- Comunicat 4 --> 
          <div class="layout-6-cols">
            <div class="release">
              <div class="release__header">
                <span class="release__header-date">02 Octubre 2017</span>
                <span class="tag-badge badgeLightBlue">Corporatiu</span>
              </div>
              <div class="release__body">
                <img class="release__body-image" src="./images/img-release-1.png" alt="images release 1">
                <p class="release__body--text">4.Connexió a internet per a tothom a tota la flota de busos de TMB</p>
              </div>
              <div class="release__footer">
                <span class="release__footer-attachedFiles">2 adjunts</span>
                <a href="#" class="release__footer-link">Llegir més</a>
              </div>
            </div>  
          </div>
      </div>                                    
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="layout-row">
        <!-- Comunicat 5 --> 
        <div class="layout-6-cols">
          <div class="release">
            <div class="release__header">
              <span class="release__header-date">02 Octubre 2017</span>
              <span class="tag-badge badgeLightBlue">Corporatiu</span>
            </div>
            <div class="release__body">
              <img class="release__body-image" src="./images/img-release-1.png" alt="images release 1">
              <p class="release__body--text">5.Connexió a internet per a tothom a tota la flota de busos de TMB</p>
            </div>
            <div class="release__footer">
              <span class="release__footer-attachedFiles">2 adjunts</span>
              <a href="#" class="release__footer-link">Llegir més</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Comunicat 6 -->
        <div class="layout-6-cols">
          <div class="release">
            <div class="release__header">
              <span class="release__header-date">02 Octubre 2017</span>
              <span class="tag-badge badgeRed">Canvis de Personals</span>
            </div>
            <div class="release__body">
              <img class="release__body-image" src="./images/img-release-1.png" alt="images release 1">
              <p class="release__body--text">6. Noves incorporacions en el departament de recursos humans</p>
            </div>
            <div class="release__footer">
              <a href="#" class="release__footer-link">Llegir més</a>
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>
      </div>                                
    </div>                                                                                                                                                  
  </div>
</div>
```

And i just need the carousel to work as bootstrap default carousel:

```
$("#carouselRecentReleases").carousel({
  interval: 5000
});
```

Any idea on how to achieve the resposive behaviour ? Have found a couple of options out there but nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Simply create two separate carousels and hide them according to `@media` query. Since you use the same resources, the overhead is insignificant.

Comment: @brooksrelyt I'm using Bootstrap 4.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, that solve the problem for sure but not the ideal approach. I'm pretty sure it can be done without duplicating the Carousel but not sure how tho. thanks anyway.

Comment: In order to do it *"on the fly"* you need to listen to changes in page width and upon detecting a change from one `@media` query interval to another you have to update the slides. Bootstrap's carousel doesn't have an option to define slides based on responsiveness level. So you have three options: **1)** use a slider which can display different slides based on responsiveness level (i.e: slick slider), **2)** write the javascript to generate slides on the fly yourself or **3)** have two sliders and display them accordingly using CSS `@media` queries. Have your pick.